# Specs2: Ignore specification with a message?

Tags: scala, testing, specs2

I need to put one of my test cases into a *"pending"* state.

I would like to assing some sort of message to it that can be displayed on the output when running the test, something like JUnit with `@Ignore("Pending: issue #1234 needs to be fixed")`.

Is there an equivalent for that with Specs2?

```
class MySpec extends mutable.Specification {
  args(skipAll = true) // Can I include a message here in the output somehow?

  "cool MyClass feature" should {
    "which is broken unfortunately" in {
      failure
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For an individual example, I believe you can use:

```
class MySpec extends mutable.Specification {

  "cool MyClass feature" should {
    "which is broken unfortunately" in {
      failure
    }.pendingUntilFixed("message about the issue")
  }

}
```

I don't know if there's a way to extend this to mark all the examples in a spec as pending with the same message, as you seem to be hoping.

Comment: You can also use `Pending("message")` instead of `failure` in the body of your example (provided that no `FailureException` is called before. In that case `pendingUntilFixed is the best approach)

Comment: Thx for the help, also @Eric for the alternative approach.

Comment: I think the answer is actually wrong - does not compile. The .pendingUntilFixed("message about the issue") has to be moved one line up.

Comment: If it's wrong, it may be because of recent changes in scala.  This answer is 2 years old, and scala's still something of a moving target.

Comment: For those new to Specs2, note that tests with `pendingUntilFixed` **[will still get run](https://coderwall.com/p/rgbj2a/use-pendinguntilfixed-to-disable-specs-temporarily)**. To skip a test completely, try [`skipped`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10974311/56285).

Comment: If I could +1 more than once, I would for @Jonik